# Numerical issue with CaputoD

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, special-functions

```
Plot[{CaputoD[MittagLefflerE[1/2, -t^(1/2)], {t, 1/2}], (-E^t)*Erfc[Sqrt[t]]}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

The two functions are equal, but the graphs are different. What's the problem?

Comment: Try: `Plot[{Evaluate@CaputoD[MittagLefflerE[1/2, -t^(1/2)], {t, 1/2}], (-E^t)*Erfc[Sqrt[t]]}, {t, 0, 1}]`

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk the 1st function is not plotted.

Comment: There is something strange with "CaputoD" and the "HoldAll" attribute of "Plot". This seems to be the reason that "CaputoD" is not evaluated in "Plot". You need "Evaluate" as Mariusz already mentioned: Plot[{ Evaluate@CaputoD[MittagLefflerE[1/2, -t^(1/2)], {t, 1/2}]}, {t,
   0, 1}]

Comment: The issue can be boiled down to the following: `t = 0; CaputoD[MittagLefflerE[1/2, -t^(1/2)], {t, 1/2}]` outputs `0`. Clearly `CaputoD` is still fragile. (Notice for e.g. `D` a warning will be given: `t = 0; D[t, t]`. ) I suggest reporting this to WRI.

Comment: @xzczd I agree, you could report it if possible

Comment: @DanielHuber how `Evaluate` solves the problem?

Comment: When plotting, if two functions are equal, only the second will be seen since it exactly overlays the first. Use the option `PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Dashed}` to see both plots.

Comment: I can only guess. However, Plot does not evaluate its arguments like ordinary functions. It receives the unevaluated argument. The reason is, that it then tries to make analytical simplifications. But then something must go wrong and CaputoD is not evaluated. On the other hand, Evaluate forces the evaluation of CaputoD before feeding it to Plot.

Comment: @DanielHuber thanks, but it doesn't evaluate if we take Evaluate@CaputoD[MittagLefflerE[1/2, -t^(1/2)]^2, {t, 1/2}]}

Comment: @S.Euler `CaputoD[MittagLefflerE[1/2, -t^(1/2)]^2, {t, 1/2}]` returns `CaputoD[E^(2 t) Erfc[Sqrt[t]]^2, {t, 1/2}]`, the `CaputoD` is still there, `Plot` won't be able to plot this, of course.

Comment: @xzczd yeah, this is an example where evaluate does not work. how can one solves this problem?

Comment: Then your question becomes, how to numerically calculate Caputo derivative when the analytic Caputo derivative isn't available, and this is a totally different problem, please consider posting it as a separate question.

Comment: @xzczd please see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/272390/74763

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I wrote in the comment, the code will evaluate if you apply "Evaluate". As it does not work in your case, you may additionally have another problem. In any case, I am showing working code with a pictures, that may help you.

Without "Evaluate":

```
Plot[{CaputoD[MittagLefflerE[1/2, -t^(1/2)], {t, 1/2}]}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

And with "Evaluate":

```
Plot[{Evaluate@CaputoD[MittagLefflerE[1/2, -t^(1/2)], {t, 1/2}]}, {t, 
  0, 1}]
```

[image]

BTW: I am using MMA 13.1

Comment: But if you square the function it doesn't evaluate

Comment: @S.Euler - The square of the function plots fine, i.e., `Plot[Evaluate[CaputoD[MittagLefflerE[1/2, -t^(1/2)], {t, 1/2}]^2], {t, 0, 1}]`

Comment: @bob By "square" OP probably means this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/272353/numerical-issue-with-caputod#comment680155_272353