# Numerical computation of Caputo dervative

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, special-functions

When trying to evaluate

```
CaputoD[MittagLefflerE[1/2, -t^(1/2)]^2, {t, 1/2}]
```

it returns

```
CaputoD[E^(2*t)*Erfc[Sqrt[t]]^2, {t, 1/2}]
```

So how we can handle such computation numerically (at least to obtain a plot) when an analytic representation is not available.

Comment: You can do it via means of a fit since `f[x_] = BSplineBasis[3, x] // PiecewiseExpand`

`CaputoD[f[x], {x, 1/2}] ` exists. So since any fit to some function can be expanded into BSplines you are in business.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only **numerically** with plot:

```
alfa = 1/2; n = Max[0, Ceiling[alfa]];
f[t_] := MittagLefflerE[1/2, -t^(1/2)]^2
g[x_?NumericQ] := 1/Gamma[n - alfa]*
NIntegrate[(x - z)^(n - alfa - 1)*D[f[z], {z, n}], {z, 0, x}](*From: ?CaputoD*)
Plot[g[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```