# CaputoD of (Edge) BSplines

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, splines, discontinuity

> tl;dr   Why does this works:

```
  CaputoD[BSplineBasis[{3, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}}, 0, x], {x, 
   1/2}] // Simplify
```

[image]

Whereas this fails

```
   CaputoD[BSplineBasis[{3, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}}, 0, x], {x, 
   1/2}] // Simplify
```

---

**Context**

Following up on this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/272390/1089),
in order to define a `NCaputoD` function which would work on
Interpolation functions, I need to be able to compute `CaputoD` of (edge)
`BSpline` such as those

```
Plot[{BSplineBasis[{3, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}}, 0, x],
  BSplineBasis[{3, {0, 0, 0, 1, 2}}, 0, x]}, {x, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

I have attempted to extract the splines of a given interpolation of a set of points and then operate on each polynomial of each segment via this function

```
Clear[NCaputoD];
NCaputoD[dat_, order_] := 
 Module[{fspl, fb, sd, scpts, sk, var, tt, x}, 
  fspl = Interpolation[dat, Method -> "Spline", 
    InterpolationOrder -> 3];
  fb = First[Cases[fspl, _BSplineFunction, ∞]];
  {sd, scpts, sk} = fb /@ {"Degree", "ControlPoints", "Knots"};
  tt = Flatten[
    Outer[Times, 
     Sequence @@ 
      MapThread[
       Table[BSplineBasis[{#1, #2}, k - 1, #3] // 
          PiecewiseExpand, {k, #4}] &, {sd, sk, {x}, 
        Dimensions[scpts]}]]];
  tt = Table[
    Piecewise@
     Transpose@
      MapAt[CaputoD[#, {x, order}] &, 
       First@(List @@ tt[[i]]) // Transpose, {1}],
    {i, Length[tt]}];
  Function[x // Evaluate, scpts . tt // Evaluate]]
```

Unfortunately, the `CaputoD` does not operate properly on the  edge splines for non integer arguments. I.e. This works

```
   ff = NCaputoD[dat, 1]; Plot[ff[x], {x, 0, 5}]
```

But this does not:

```
   ff = NCaputoD[dat, 1/2];Plot[ff[x], {x, 0, 5}]
```

Having defined

```
f[t_] = MittagLefflerE[1/2, -t^(1/2)]^2
dat = Table[{t, f[t]}, {t, 0, 5, 1/2}] // N;
Plot[f[t], {t, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Could it be because `BSplineBasis[{3, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}}, 0, x]` is not differentiable at zero? `Plot[BSplineBasis[{3, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}}, 0, x], {x, -1, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> All]`  Can `CaputoD` take fractional derivative of non-differentiable function?  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuvXs.png)

Comment: @Nasser, may be not! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is just because `CaputoD` is still fragile. Let's take a closer look at `BSplineBasis[{3, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}}, 0, x]`:

```
BSplineBasis[{3, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}}, 0, x] // PiecewiseExpand
(* Piecewise[{{1 - 3*x + 3*x^2 - x^3, 0 <= x <= 1}}, 0] *)
```

By definition `CaputoD[expr, {x, α}]` is an integral defined in $[0,x]$. I'm not experienced in fractional derivative, but reading the output of `CaputoD[BSplineBasis[{3, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}}, 0, x], {x, 1/2}]`, it seems that we always have $x\geq 0$, so

```
CaputoD[BSplineBasis[{3, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}}, 0, x], {x, 1/2}]
```

is equivalent to

```
CaputoD[Piecewise[{{1 - 3*x + 3*x^2 - x^3, x <= 1}}, 0], {x, 1/2}]
```

and `CaputoD` outputs the following instantly:

```
(* Piecewise[{{-((2*Sqrt[x]*(15 - 20*x + 8*x^2))/(5*Sqrt[Pi])), 
       x <= 1}}, (2*(-8 - 15*Sqrt[-1 + x]*Sqrt[x] + 24*x + 
           20*Sqrt[-1 + x]*x^(3/2) - 24*x^2 - 8*Sqrt[-1 + x]*x^(5/2) + 
           8*x^3))/(5*Sqrt[Pi]*Sqrt[-1 + x])] *)
```

To automate this simplification, we can add `x >= 0` as an assumption of `PiecewiseExpand`:

```
Assuming[{x>=0}, BSplineBasis[{3, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}}, 0, x] // PiecewiseExpand] //  
 CaputoD[#, {x, 1/2}] &
```

### Remark

Even if $x$ is allowed to be negative, `CaputoD` shouldn't have difficulty in handling the expression because `BSplineBasis[{3, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}}, 0, x] == 0` for $x<0$.

Comment: Thanks: so it seems: `BSplineBasis[{3, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}}, 0, x] // 
   PiecewiseExpand // # /. \!\(TraditionalForm\`Inequality[0, 
        LessEqual, x, LessEqual, 1]\) ->
     \!\(TraditionalForm\`Inequality[x, LessEqual, 1]\) & //
 CaputoD[#, {x, 1/2}] &` works

Comment: and so does `BSplineBasis[{3, {0, 0, 0, 1, 2}}, 0, x] // 
   PiecewiseExpand // # /. \!\(TraditionalForm\`Inequality[0, 
        LessEqual, x, Less, 1]\) ->
     \!\(TraditionalForm\`Inequality[x, LessEqual, 1]\) & //
 CaputoD[#, {x, 1/2}] &`

Comment: @chris I find a more general solution :) , see my update.